# Emacs fix the indentation of the java-mode

Tags: emacs

Suppose that code :

```
  Command provisionHostCommand = new Command() {
      @Override
      public void execute() {
        final List<Host> hosts = new ArrayList<Host>(display.getSelectionModel().getSelectedSet());
        eventBus.fireEvent(new ProvisioningHostEvent(hosts));
      }
    };
```

Take a look about the indention. There's 4 spaces for the Command anonymous class. I have my c-basic-offset set to 2. How can I reduce the indentation space in a anonymous class ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this seems to work for me:

```
(c-set-offset 'inexpr-class 0)
```

I'm not quite sure why, though, I've looked at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Indentation-Calculation) and it seems to suggest that anonymous classes should only be indented by `c-basic-offset`. Perhaps they're indented twice because of the opening curly brace?

**Edit**: How about this workaround from http://www.mail-archive.com/jde@sunsite.auc.dk/msg01159.html?

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
              '(lambda ()
                     (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
                     (if (assoc 'inexpr-class c-offsets-alist)
                             (c-set-offset 'inexpr-class 0))))
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I try with c-basic-offset to 3, and the line is indented twice (6 spaces). How can I fix the bug ?